# Is is possible to concatenate values from two different objects in Jolt

Tags: concatenation, jolt

I would like to know if it is possible in Jolt to concatenate values from different objects.  I've successfully concatenated "orderType" (value=ABC) and "minorCode" (value 0003) from the "orderInformation" object to create an output key of "Job.JobTypeCd" (value ABC0003).  I would like to add the "serviceType" value as a prefix to that new key so the output value would be "123ABC0003".

Example input

```
{
  "orderInformation": {
    "orderType": "ABC",
    "minorCode": "0003"
  },
  "account": {
    "serviceType": "123"
  }
}
```

Current Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "orderInformation": {
        "JobType": "=concat(@(1,orderType),@(1,minorCode))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "orderInformation": {
        "JobType": "Job.JobTypeCd"
      },
      "account": {
        "serviceType": "Job.AddThisAsPrefix2JobTypeCd"
      }
    }
      }
]
```

Current output

```
{
  "Job" : {
    "JobTypeCd" : "ABC0003",
    "AddThisAsPrefix2JobTypeCd" : "123"
  }
}
```

Desired output

```
{
  "Job" : {
    "JobTypeCd" : "123ABC0003"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the `serviceType` value to the same `concat` operation as below.

```
"JobType": "=concat(@(2,account.serviceType),@(1,orderType),@(1,minorCode))"
```

Full spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "orderInformation": {
        "JobType": "=concat(@(2,account.serviceType),@(1,orderType),@(1,minorCode))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "orderInformation": {
        "JobType": "Job.JobTypeCd"
      }
    }
   }
]
```